# What is the procedure of salat in case of injury in leg making it difficult (opens the wound) to perform sajdah?

Tags: salat, fiqh

I have an injury in my left foot downwards from knee. I can easily walk and run but while in salat in the state of sajdah when the injury is touching floor it hurts and also stretches which tends to open the wound.

Can I use chair in this case or what is the alternate way? Or do I have to pray in the same manner regardless of injury?

*Answers from Quran and hadith would be appreciated.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

assallammu'alaikum. syafakallah. may Allah make your wound heal faster.
The short answer is: yes you can use chair.
There is a hadith that states about this,

> Narrated by Imran bin Husain:
>   had piles, so I asked the Prophet (ﷺ) about the prayer. He said, "Pray while standing and if you can't, pray while sitting and if you cannot do even that, then pray Lying on your side."

Reference    : Sahih al-Bukhari 1117
In-book reference    : Book 18, Hadith 37
USC-MSA web (English) reference  : Vol. 2, Book 20, Hadith 218